# Turbolinks causes ReactDOM to render a second time after clicking back button

Tags: react-router

When I press the back button in my app, a second root component gets created. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var history = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');

<Router history={history()}>
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route .../>
    <Route .../>
    <Route .../>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The problem turned out to be that Turbolinks was enabled. Since my app is SPA throughout, I just removed `//= require turbolinks` from my application.js.

[image]

Comment: No idea, weird! Just a hunch, can you try a console log just before you define your router and one just before you connect it to your DOM to see if both run possible twice?

Comment: Looks like `ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));` is getting called twice. I have that wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {});` Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: Yeah no need for jQuery there (or in general really when you're using React). What happens if you try and place it outside of the document.ready()?

Comment: Yeah I removed it but still the same thing. It looks like my entire application.js is getting called twice. This is a rails app `console.log('run');
var application = require('v2/application');
application();` "Run" is called once on page load, and once again after pressing back.

Comment: Found the culprit, it was turbolinks.

Comment: Sweet! Perhaps we can try and update the question etc so for future people who encounter your situation this is usable?

Comment: Not sure if an answer from me is warranted since you found the culprit yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It certainly made me discover the problem faster :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by disabling cache for turbolinks.

```
<head>
 ...
  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">
</head>
```

document are here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#opting-out-of-caching

I think turbolinks load the cached js files and then load the fetched js files, which may cause your react component to render twice